# What's the difference between an URL Type and an URL Scheme?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone have a good explanation of that?

Answer (score 3):

They're the same thing.

But here's how they might mean different things:

For example, iTunes uses the `itms://` scheme when in fact HTTP is used as the transport protocol, so you can replace `itms` with `http` and get the same results. Similarly, `feed://` is commonly used for RSS feeds, but the underlying transport protocol is still HTTP.

So `itms` and `feed` are not URL schemes in a strict sense. Their sole purpose is to trigger special applications (iTunes or an RSS reader).

I imagine Type and Scheme might be used to differentiate between schemes that correspond to a transport protocol, and those that don't.

Can you point out a particular resource that led you to believe they're different things?